# Disabling rotation for ViewController in NavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

Is it even possible to disable rotation when the View Controller I want to disable it in is
in a Navigation Controller that supports all directions? for one special view I want only portrait mode to be allowed, I´v tried about everything but nothing seems to work - I am guessing this is cause the View Controller is part of a Navigation Controller with segues?

Answer (score 0):

By Default any property or a setting of a Super View is applied on all the sub-views inside it. Therefore even if you block the View Controller it will rotate because it is in **Navigation Controller** that allows rotation. Therefore i would suggest that you create a property in your `AppDelegate` that sets the orientation settings and then haldle it from `ViewControllers`